# Create a custom Journey Builder activity in App Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, appcenter

I understand that you will need to create an app within App Center to be able to connect to Journey Builder within your Marketing Cloud account.

The issue I'm facing is that the app extensions related options to create a Journey Builder activity isn't available.

Does anyone know how this can be created?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need an app extension related to journey builder at this point.

One the first step, you need to select "Package" , connect your app to your production environment and give it the required permissions. Once it is configured properly and your web service is running, the app will appear in the activities panel of your journey builder screen.

After you have created these, click on the app and click on activities. There you have the option of adding your application extension.